# What is the difference between these two official PS3 headsets?

Tags: ps3

Is one newer? Are they both official and are there any other official headset solutions?

Is it pointless to pay more for official headsets?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have any other information about them? (Name, model, link to where they can be bought?)

Comment: @AshleyNunn http://bit.ly/yrun6d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are both official headsets, the top one came out on October 2008 and the bottom one was announced November 2010 and replaced it. They have identical features and use, with the latter model having better audio cancelation technology.

There's another official PS3 headset, the Official Stereo Headset, which is used for the game's audio as well as voice chat. It connects to the console by USB (not BlueTooth as the other headsets) offers virtual surround set as well and is more expensive than the voice chat headsets.

You can read about both [on this WikiPedia page.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayStation_3_accessories#Headsets)

As for paying more for the official headsets - it's all up to you. The Sony BlueTooth headsets cost more than other brands but in my opinion offer better quality. Sony's official headsets have the advantage of offering other features on the console that other headsets don't support, like on-screen status indicator and "HQ Mode" which Sony claims offers better sound quality. In my experience playing online, you can tell which users use the official headset and which don't by their voice clarity.